# Restructuring a Subversion Repository without losing any history

Tags: svn, migration, repository, transition

Having asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611237/subversion-repository-layout) and received a very satisfactory answer, I now wish in hindisght that I had made a different choice for the layout of my subversion repository.

My repo layout is currently:

```
/trunk
      /Project1
      /Project2
/branches
         /Project1
             /Branch1
             /Branch2
         /Project2
/tags
     /Project1
          /Tag1
          /Tag2
     /Project2
```

Of course now I wish I'd made the other decision:

```
/Project1
         /trunk
         /branches
         /tags
/Project2
         /trunk
         /branches
         /tags
```

So the question now becomes: how can I make this transition, while keeping my version history intact? Is there a way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to do `svn move` Your history will remain intact, but of course, new revisions will be added for every move.

```
svn move http://server/repo/branches/Project1/ http://server/repo/Project1/branches/Branch1 -m "Moving branch1 of project1"
```

The above is server side move ( rename )

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html

Comment: That would certainly work, I'd want to automate it though (lots of projects). What I really wanted though, is a way to take the repository apart and put it back together again _as if it had always had the new layout_. Perhaps that is asking too much.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but it didn't really answer my question completely. For the record, the reason I wanted to do this was because we use an analysis tool that doesn't really understand moves too well. In other words, I wanted no record of the moves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use [svn move](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/edguide/chapter03.html#ch03-moving) (or svn rename)