# SVN Structure for new version of app

Tags: android, svn

I am working on new version of an app. What SVN structure should I use for creating the new version of the app?  Should there be a trunk and than branches for each version 1.0, 1.2 etc? 1.2 is really based on 1.0 and not on the trunk?  So I would like clarification on how to structure this? Its really a several projects like model, ui etc and and the model does not change quite so much with reach major version/release, but the ui project does.  So I would like advice on how to setup branches for say version 1.2.  Also with SVN should each developer have their own branch?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611237/subversion-repository-layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting a new project, it is good to start with typical layout like this:

- trunk
- tags
- branches

At least the trunk should be created initially, as you will probably put your initial code there.

Under branches, you can store feature or maintenance clones of the trunk, or just any other branches.

In any case, all this is just a widely used convention; SVN functionality does not depend on naming or layout at all. However, some higher-level tools can - for instance maven-release-plugin...

Comment: I think this is the right structure.  Now when should a separate branch be created for and android app?  I mean the lets say you build an app for new years day, and it changes each new years.  Its going to be quite a bit different perhaps each time.  Or there will be lots of assets that will never be pushed back into trunk. So I am also looking for criteria for creating a new branch.

Comment: Also could you clarify creating branch vs. copy command.  Is there a difference?

Comment: in svn, copying is the way of creating branches; read SVN's excellent docs about it: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html

Answer (score 0):

Before you commit to SVN, please, take a few minutes to read http://hginit.com/ and think about using distributed version control system (DVCS), like Mercurial or Git. It makes life so much easier.

Comment: This does not answer the question IMHO (maybe NextDroid has no choice over his version control system); it should actually be a comment.